# Turn SQL (Oracle) into PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm making report of created issues in pl/sql. I have many separated sql's and I want to have one pl/sql query which write me a text report with values from database.

How to turn this sql query into pl/sql:

```
select a1.name, count(*)
  from sin.incident a2, sin.people a1
 where a2.assignee = a1.id
 and a2.created_date >= (TO_DATE('&date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
 and a2.parent_problem is NULL
 and a1.assignee_group = '10003'
 group by cube (a1.name, a2.created_date);
```

Result of pl/sql query should be:

The best in this month was ... who created ... issues

The second was ... who created ... issues

... created ... issues

... created ... issues
.
.
.

Answers:
I just want to have one pl/sql query made from many sql queries.
There is no limit of persons, but here would be 2-5 persons.
My boss wants to get it in pl/sql.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Is there a limit to the number you report on e.g. upto the tenth person?

Comment: PL/SQL is not a "query"  It is a programming language that you can execute SQL statements in.  Why can't you just write a script in SQLPLUS to execute the queries you want and spool the results to a file?

Comment: The boss is Professor X?  seems arbitrary to use pl/sql when you might do it all in a single query

Comment: Did you know about [`WITH` SQL clause](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cursors and cursor loops, e.g.:

```
PROCEDURE print_data IS
    CURSOR my_data IS
    select a1.name, count(*) cnt
      from sin.incident a2, sin.people a1
     where a2.assignee = a1.id
       and a2.created_date >= (TO_DATE('&date', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
       and a2.parent_problem is NULL
       and a1.assignee_group = '10003'
     group by cube (a1.name, a2.created_date);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN my_data LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || rec.name || ' count:' || rec.cnt);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Check out [this example](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php) as well. Don't forget to enable output and to set buffer size if you use `dbms_output.put_line` (see [here](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.de/2005/10/dbmsoutputputline.html) for more).

Good luck!